# make new git repository by copying old one

Tags: git, bitbucket, versioning, commit

I have my app `crazy_app` and I want to use all of this sites files to make new website called `world_app`.

I copied `crazy_app` files and renamed folder to `world_app` problem is that, when I open it its still in master branch from previous app. How can I make new repository in Bitbucket from `world_app`?

I just need to copy app and use both separately!

Comment: have you tried to fork it?

Comment: @AndrewKress no I haven't don't know how it works.

Comment: Are you trying to start a fresh repo with no history from "crazy_app"?  If that's the case you can just delete the `.git` folder in "world_app" and re-initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BitBucket, you can fork by opening the repository and clicking the Fork link under actions:

[image]

Comment: after fork how can I pull this repository to my workspace?

Comment: Clone it.  Then you will have a separate local git repository.  Obviously you will need to make all the changes to file names and such to match your new app.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate a repo like so:
https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

A "fork" is a repo that is based on another one, but begins to track its own changes separately. https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/